# How can I overcome an “ Couldn't open device ” error when trying to erase an external USB disk?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, external-disk

So I'm trying to erase the disk after making it to a bootable usb but now I’m getting this error "Couldn't open device". This happened before and after a reboot.

I've tried first aiding it first and erase it and using other format  I've tried using terminal to erase, got the same error every time.

[image]

[image]
diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
    
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.1 GB   disk0s2
    
    /dev/disk1 (synthesized):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                                     Physical Store disk0s2
       1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            57.9 GB    disk1s1
       2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.7 MB    disk1s2
       3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.4 MB   disk1s3
       4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
    
    /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:                                                   *4.2 GB     disk2
```

So how can I erase /dev/disk2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected a partition in Disk Utility, or the entire device?

Carbon Copy Cloner has an excellent, [detailed set of instructions available online.](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/preparing-your-backup-disk-backup-os-x#high_sierra) You didn't tell us which macOS version you're using (in the future, remember that will help!), but this page has instructions from Catalina all the way back to `Yosemite`.

Let us know if you're still having problems after trying this.

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything but still it says couldn't open device. I use macOS mojave

Comment: I can't imagine what could be causing this... maybe a failed disk? Is it new, used - recently? Have you tried it in another system?

Comment: It's new just bought it and im sure it's not broken

Answer (score 0):

You can start disk utility and select the disk you want to erase. Now go to Partition in Disk Utility and adjust the size or add a partition. Doing this should erase your disk. if there are no partitions add one and make it include the whole disk!

Comment: I forgot to write but i've tried erasing with disk utility but still couldn't open device